# Execute a JS init() function from another file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I picked a [Jquery plugin from Codepen](http://codepen.io/ykob/pen/KdZYYm) to use on my website and I need some help integrating it. The JS file includes a function called `init();` which expectedly gets the ball rolling.

Now since I'm new to JS I was wondering is it possible to execute this function from another file like most popular plugins do, for instance `new WOW().init();` which initializes wow animations.

How would I go about modifying the function to allow for this?

Comment: How are you importing this module? I believe it uses `Require.js` but not sure. Also to call a function from a module, this a sample: `var mod = require('moduleName'); mod.init()`. Hope it helps

Comment: I didn't needed require.js for it to work. I just added a div where the module will be dislayed, css to style it and simply added the required files like so `<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r72/three.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/tech-field.js"></script>`. Tech-field.js contains all the js code from the codepen